# FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink() always returning null on Android

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm using **firebase_dynamic_links** for **passwordless login** with firebase and **getInitialLink()** is always returning **null** on **version 0.5.0+8**.
If I use **version 0.4.0+4** and **retrieveDynamicLink()** instead of **getInitialLink()** it works fine.

Since it's working in version 0.4.0+4 I assume the problem is not on Firebase settings.
This is how I'm sending the email:

```
final FirebaseAuth user = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    try {
      user.sendSignInWithEmailLink(
          email: _email,
          androidInstallIfNotAvailable: true,
          iOSBundleID: "com.mydomain.myappname",
          androidMinimumVersion: "16",
          androidPackageName: "com.mydomain.myappname",
          url: "https://myAppName.page.link/fJc4",
          handleCodeInApp: true);
    } catch (e) {
      _showDialog(e.toString());
      return false;
    }
```

And then to retrieve it:

```
@override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      _retrieveDynamicLink();
    }
  }

  Future<void> _retrieveDynamicLink() async {
    final PendingDynamicLinkData data = await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
    print('data == ' + data.toString());

    final Uri deepLink = data?.link;
    print(deepLink.toString());

    if (deepLink != null) {
      _link = deepLink.toString();
      _signInWithEmailAndLink();
    }
    return deepLink.toString();
  }
```

data is always **null** on the new version with **getInitialLink()**. It works on the previous version with **retrieveDynamicLink()**.

I created a new project just to test it and the problem persists. The only other change I made to the project, besides the view files was add **firebase_auth: ^0.15.0+1** to **pubspc.yaml**

> Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v): [√]
>
> Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.6, on Microsoft Windows
> [Version 10.0.17763.864], locale pt-BR)
>
> [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDKversion 28.0.3)
>
> [√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
>
> [!] VS Code (version 1.40.0) X Flutter extension not installed; install from https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter
>
> [√] Connected device (1 available)
>
> ! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @BenjaminSmith Nope. And no answer from them either. I'm just using version 0.4.0+4 and everything works fine.

Comment: check this answer, it may help. This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67904367/6661043

Answer (score 7, accepted):

getInitialLink() only works if opened via a dynamic link (see plugin document), not when the application is active or in background (for this you need to call onLink).

```
  void initDynamicLinks() async {
    final PendingDynamicLinkData data = await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
    final Uri deepLink = data?.link;    if (deepLink != null) {
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, deepLink.path);
    }

    FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink(
      onSuccess: (PendingDynamicLinkData dynamicLink) async {
        final Uri deepLink = dynamicLink?.link;

        if (deepLink != null) {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, deepLink.path);
        }
      },
      onError: (OnLinkErrorException e) async {
        print('onLinkError');
        print(e.message);
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

please you may use this plugin instead [app_links](https://pub.dev/packages/app_links)

because **firebase_dynamic_links** has bugs at the moment.

Comment: It's true, I dropped in app_links as a replacement and it works without issues. There is something wrong with Firebase Dynamic Links.

Comment: I filed an issue [here](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/8926) but the last few issues for this same bug were closed without resolution.

Comment: I spend a few hours on it, but eventually went with app_links and had it working in 10 minutes for all use cases. Dynamic_links has lots of bugs and the documentation isn't the best

Answer (score 1):

ensure that you get started dynamic link in firebase project[image]